# Generating a migration with Sequel

Tags: ruby, migration, sequel

I'm using Sequel.

How can I generate a migration file, even empty, so that its name will be something like `20160313142249_create_table1.rb` ?

Namely, how can I get it to generate the "20160313142249" part? Can Sequel do that?

Comment: Use the [TimestampMigrator](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/migration.rdoc#timestampmigrator-filenames). It will be used automatically if the version of the migration name is greater that 20000101. Something like `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S` in a bash-like shell will generate the timestamp for you, or you can write your little generator in a Rake task using `strftime`.

Answer (score 5):

Sequel does not come with handy Rake tasks that generate migration files, but you can write your own. This very simple one can be used as an example.

```
# Rakefile
namespace :db do
  desc "Generate migration file"
  task :generate_migration, [:file_name] do |task, args|
    filename = args.file_name
    time = Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%L")
    sh "touch migrate/#{time}_#{filename}.rb"
  end
end
```

Now the usage is a simple as `rake db:generate_migration[file_name]`.